# use instance of object inside a function

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to find the best way to use an instance of my connection inside a function, but I don't know if I should pass it in as a parameter of my function or use a global.

This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once('class/connexion.php');

$cx = Connexion::getConnexion();


function get_customers(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    $select = $cx->prepare($query);
    $select->execute();
    $result = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result
}


get_customers();

?>
```

Comment: you should pass it in (ie, dependency injection) as that is considered the better practice by the community. globals are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

Pass it as argument:

```
<?php
require_once('class/connexion.php');

$cx = Connexion::getConnexion();


function get_customers($cx){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    $select = $cx->prepare($query);
    $select->execute();
    $result = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $result
 }


get_customers($cx);

?>
```